# Why I can't get an answer for the Ship Puzzle with Prolog?

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle

I need to solve the Ship Puzzle problem with using Prolog.
Here are the facts.

> There are 5 ships.
>
> 1. The Greek ship leaves at six and carries coffee.
> 2. The Ship in the middle has a black chimney.
> 3. The English ship leaves at nine.
> 4. The French ship with blue chimney is to the left of a ship that carries coffee.
> 5. To the right of the ship carrying cocoa is a ship going to Marseille.
> 6. The Brazilian ship is heading for Manila.
> 7. Next to the ship carrying rice is a ship with a green chimney.
> 8. A ship going to Genoa leaves at five.
> 9. The Spanish ship leaves at seven and is to the right of the ship going to Marseille.
> 10. The ship with a red chimney goes to Hamburg.
> 11. Next to the ship leaving at seven is a ship with a white chimney.
> 12. The ship on the border carries corn.
> 13. The ship with a black chimney leaves at eight.
> 14. The ship carrying corn is anchored next to the ship carrying rice.
> 15. The ship to Hamburg leaves at six.
>
> Which ship goes to Port Said? Which ship carries tea?

I search internet for answers, but I could not find any. So I refer 'The Zebra Puzzle' and accordingly I arranged the code for this problem. So this is my Prolog code the problem.

```
exists(A,(A,_,_,_,_)).
exists(A,(_,A,_,_,_)).
exists(A,(_,_,A,_,_)).
exists(A,(_,_,_,A,_)).
exists(A,(_,_,_,_,A)).

rightOf(A,B,(B,A,_,_,_)).
rightOf(A,B,(_,B,A,_,_)).
rightOf(A,B,(_,_,B,A,_)).
rightOf(A,B,(_,_,_,B,A)).

middleShip(A,(_,_,A,_,_)).

lastShip(A,(_,_,_,_,A)).

nextTo(A,B,(B,A,_,_,_)).
nextTo(A,B,(_,B,A,_,_)).
nextTo(A,B,(_,_,B,A,_)).
nextTo(A,B,(_,_,_,B,A)).
nextTo(A,B,(A,B,_,_,_)).
nextTo(A,B,(_,A,B,_,_)).
nextTo(A,B,(_,_,A,B,_)).
nextTo(A,B,(_,_,_,A,B)).

solution(PortSaidShip, TeaCarrier) :-
   Shipes = (ship(_,_,_,_,_),ship(_,_,_,_,_),ship(_,_,_,_,_),ship(_,_,_,_,_),ship(_,_,_,_,_)),
   exists(ship('Greek',6,'Coffee',_,_),Shipes),
   middleShip(ship(_,_,_,_,'Black',_),Shipes),
   exists(ship('English',9,_,_,_),Shipes),
   rightOf(ship(_,_,'Coffee',_,_),ship('French',_,_,'Blue',_),Shipes),
   rightOf(ship(_,_,_,_,'Marseille'),ship(_,_,'Cocoa',_,_),Shipes),
   exists(ship('Brazilian',_,_,_,'Manila'),Shipes),
   nextTo(ship(_,_,_,'Green',_),ship(_,_,'Rice',_,_),Shipes),
   exists(ship(_,5,_,_,'Genoa'),Shipes),
   rightOf(ship('Spanish',7,_,_,_),ship(_,_,_,_,'Marseille'),Shipes),
   exists(ship(_,_,_,'Red','Hamburg'),Shipes),
   nextTo(ship(_,_,_,'White',_),ship(_,7,_,_,_),Shipes),
   lastShip(ship(_,_,'Corn',_,_),Shipes),
   exists(ship(_,8,_,'Black',_),Shipes),
   nextTo(ship(_,_,'Corn',_,_),ship(_,_,'Rice',_,_),Shipes),
   exists(ship(_,6,_,_,'Hamburg'),Shipes),
   exists(ship(PortSaidShip,_,_,_,'Port Said'),Shipes),
   exists(ship(TeaCarrier,_,'Tea',_,_),Shipes).
```

But when I run the program it will say 'false'.
So how can I solve this?
thank you

Comment: What is the *exact* query you are executing which returns the 'false'?

Comment: try to analyze subgoals of your solution. if you have the rule `solution :- A, B, C, D, E.` it mai fail because `A` failed, or `B` failed, or ..., or `E` failed. try to inspect the individual goals and which result they give you.

Comment: @MartynA: Since already the **most general query** of the only predicate that uses all other definitions fails, it can be only that query.

Comment: @false:  We may be talking at cross-purposes.  What query are you *assuming* the OP is trying to execute?

Comment: `solution(PortSaidShip, TeaCarrier)` which is the most general one. That is, any more specific one will fail as well.

Comment: to avoid typos, we can [let the computer discover](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20092493/849891) the problem's [object's attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20408402/849891) for us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You asked:

> So how can I solve this?

The following is a general methodology, that always works for pure, monotonic Prolog programs like yours. Your actual problem is that a specific goal should succeed, but it fails. So you got an **unexpected failure**. To localize the responsible part of your program, we will now systematically generalize your program. Step by step. Until we have a tiny little program fragment. This technique is called sometimes **program slicing** and sometimes **program modification**.

First of all, add the following to your code:

```
:- op(950, fy, *).
*_.

:- initialization(solution(_Port, _Carrier)).
```

Now we will remove one goal after the other by adding a **`*`** in front of it and then rerun your program. So be prepared that you will rerun your program for a couple of times. To load the program enter at the toplevel:

```
?- [shipes].
```

This works virtually everywhere, like in SICStus, GNU, SWI, YAP. You will get now a warning about a "failed directive" or similar. So - be happy - for you can now reproduce the problem with ease!

Start adding a **`*`** at the last goal. You might try several at once. 
To reload after modification you might reenter that goal, or

- in SICStus, better state `ensure_loaded(shipes).` This checks if the file has been modified and only reruns it if it has been reloaded
- in SWI, enter `make.`

Finally, I got the following program fragment:

```
middleShip(A,(_,_,A,_,_)).

solution(PortSaidShip, TeaCarrier) :-
   Shipes = (ship(_,_,_,_,_),ship(_,_,_,_,_),ship(_,_,_,_,_),ship(_,_,_,_,_),ship(_,_,_,_,_)),
   * exists(ship('Greek',6,'Coffee',_,_),Shipes),
   middleShip(ship(_,_,_,_,'Black',_),Shipes),
   * exists(ship('English',9,_,_,_),Shipes),
   * rightOf(ship(_,_,'Coffee',_,_),ship('French',_,_,'Blue',_),Shipes),
   * rightOf(ship(_,_,_,_,'Marseille'),ship(_,_,'Cocoa',_,_),Shipes),
   * exists(ship('Brazilian',_,_,_,'Manila'),Shipes),
   * nextTo(ship(_,_,_,'Green',_),ship(_,_,'Rice',_,_),Shipes),
   * exists(ship(_,5,_,_,'Genoa'),Shipes),
   * rightOf(ship('Spanish',7,_,_,_),ship(_,_,_,_,'Marseille'),Shipes),
   * exists(ship(_,_,_,'Red','Hamburg'),Shipes),
   * nextTo(ship(_,_,_,'White',_),ship(_,7,_,_,_),Shipes),
   * lastShip(ship(_,_,'Corn',_,_),Shipes),
   * exists(ship(_,8,_,'Black',_),Shipes),
   * nextTo(ship(_,_,'Corn',_,_),ship(_,_,'Rice',_,_),Shipes),
   * exists(ship(_,6,_,_,'Hamburg'),Shipes),
   * exists(ship(PortSaidShip,_,_,_,'Port Said'),Shipes),
   * exists(ship(TeaCarrier,_,'Tea',_,_),Shipes).
```

So you need to understand four lines of code to understand your problem!

As others have already indicated, the problem is that once you use `ship/6` and in other situations `ship/5`.

Another remark: In stead of `(_,_,_,A,B)` better write `[_,_,_,A,B]` which is the common list notation.

Comment: Why not use % ?

Comment: "Why not use %": Singleton variable warnings, the last goal before the `.` cannot be handled that way, nor round brackets around disjunction.

Comment: Yeah, seems legit. Some of the problems can be solved by /* */, but yes comments in general might cause new problems, also in other programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

The number of arguments to the term `ship(...)` in the second line (after solution predicate) is wrong. It is:

```
middleShip(ship(_,_,_,_,'Black',_),Shipes),
```

while it should be:

```
middleShip(ship(_,_,_,'Black',_),Shipes),
```

I haven't checked if this works, but this is causing your solver to fail for sure.

Comment: after the suggested correction, `?- solution(PortSaidShip, TeaCarrier).
PortSaidShip = 'Spanish',
TeaCarrier = 'French' ;
false.
`