# Prolog logical task with pigs

Tags: prolog, logic, zebra-puzzle

There are four pigs (`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`); they are from four different countries (`australia`,`germany`,`france`,`ireland`);
and they eat different meals (`grass`,`vegies`,`eggs`,`chestnuts`).

the pig `b` is from Germany. The Australian pig eats vegies. The Irish pig doesn't eat eggs. The pig C eats chestnuts, and pig A is not from France and it eats grass.

Which pig is from where and what does it eat?
Could someone give with a hand with this one?

Comment: Although not exactly the same problem, Einstein's Riddle has similar properties and there are [many examples of questions regarding that problem on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprolog%5Deinstein+riddle). You might want to look at some of those to get an idea on how to organize your thoughts on this problem.

Comment: check out [this entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176445/riddle-with-gnu-prolog-similar-to-einstein-riddle) with a *very* similar puzzle about guinea pigs, what they eat and how they sound.